# Creating dynamic generics at runtime using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dynamic

I'm trying to convert a **Dictionary**< **dynamic**, **dynamic** >  to a statically-typed one by examining the types of the keys and values and creating a new Dictionary of the appropriate types using Reflection.  If I know the key and value types, I can do the following:

```
Type dictType = typeof(Dictionary<,>);

        newDict = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { keyType, valueType }));
```

However, I may need to create, for example, a **Dictionary**< **MyKeyType**, **dynamic** > if the values are not all of the same type, and I can't figure out how to specify the dynamic type, since

```
typeof(dynamic)
```

isn't viable.

How would I go about doing this, and/or is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That aside, what is the usecase? creating the dictionaries via reflection and filling them with data ought to be slower than the performance overhead of using dynamic?

Answer (score 4):

The C# compiler emits System.Object as the type for "dynamic". "dynamic" is a language-specific construct and has no corresponding type in the Common Language Infrastructure.  As such, you won't be able to use reflection to create a "dynamic" nor use "dynamic" as a generic type parameter.

A Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> is really a Dictionary<object, object>.  What "dynamic" means to the compiler is simply late-bind any member accesses for the object using reflection (the implementation of which lies in the Microsoft.CSharp assembly in case you're curious).

On a side note, the compiler will also emit an attribute, DynamicAttribute, on fields, parameters, etc. that are "dynamic"; that allows people consuming the assembly's metadata to distinguish between a System.Object and a "dynamic".  This is how IntelliSense shows a method's parameter as dynamic from an assembly reference, for example.

Comment: As someone who wrote a metadata signature blob parser that shipped in VS 2010, let me tell you that properly handling DynamicAttribute is a real pain :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<MyType, Object>

Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>));
```

This actually creates a `Dictionary<Object, Object>`

The only use I can see from using dynamic instead of object is during code typing you can use dic["some"].MyDynProperty.... but if you create you object with Activator it will return Object so no use in code typing...